# matplotlib combine plots that are produced by other module

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I would like to combine a few plots, each produced by pyblock, in one figure.

```
for key in reblock_data.columns.levels[0].values:
     pbl.plot.plot_reblocking(reblock_data.xs(key,level=0,axis=1,drop_level=False))
plt.show()
```

This does not work, but rather produces a seperate figure for each key.

Maybe someone with more background could help me combine those figures.

Here is the respective doc for pyblock: [pyblock.plot](http://pyblock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyblock.plot.html)

The return of the method is `class matplotlib.figure.Figure`. Does that mean I can not combine two of them?

Comment: The `plot_reblocking` function creates a figure with multiple axes, so you cannot just combine them into one figure easily. But you can try to understand what the function does and roll your own. The source is at https://github.com/jsspencer/pyblock/blob/master/pyblock/plot.py .